# angular4 Error- cannot read property parentnode of null and 'querySelector' not working

Tags: angular

Getting error- Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null at htDashboardComponent.activeTab. I have mentioned in the code where error is occuring.
The problem as far as I recognise:

```
 this.setActive([
               tabsEl.querySelector(`#${id}`),
                tabsEl.querySelector(`[href="#${id}"]`).parentNode   
                        ]);
```

`is not setting 'active' class initially at  <li class="tab-link" *ngFor="let tab of tabsdata;let i = index;"> </li>` `at tab.component.html` and 
at

```
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content rmpm" role="tabpanel"></div>
```

However, `clicking on tab is displaying <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content rmpm" role="tabpanel"></div` `contents and other 'tab' contents as well respectively.`

### jsondata.json

```
{
    "tabsdata": ["o", "hhh", "Sph", "Custh", "Fieh", "Audh", "Digih"]
}
```

### tab.component.html

```
<ul class=" nav nav-tabs " role="tablist">
    <li class="tab-link" *ngFor="let tab of tabsdata;let i = index;">
        <a (click)="tabsUL($event)" href="#tab-{{i+1}}" role="tab">{{tab}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, `instead of passing  tabsData=[] and using service to get tabsData from  jsondata.json in tab.component.ts` , 
    if we directly pass 
     `tabsdata = ["o", "hhh", "Sph", "Custh", "Fieh", "Audh", "Digih"];` the code works.

### tab.component.ts

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-tab',
      templateUrl: './tab.component.html',
    })
          @Input() tabsdata: any;
          @Output() loadEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  tabsUL(param1): any {
    this.loadEvent.emit({ param1 });
  }
```

### htDashboard-Component.component.html

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 <app-tab [tabsdata]='tabsData' (loadEvent)=loadEvtabsUL($event)></app-tab>
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

     <div class="col-xs-12 rmpm">
            <div class="tabs tabsMenu" #tabs>
        </div>
        </div>
       <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content rmpm" role="tabpanel">
    </div>
     <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content" role="tabpanel">
    </div>
```

### htDashboard-Component.component.ts

```
//tabsdata = ["o", "hhh", "Sph", "Custh", "Fieh", "Audh", "Digih"];  -->no error
tabsData  = [];          ---> creating error
     // tab content show handle starts here
         @ViewChild('err') err: ElementRef;
        constructor(private el: ElementRef, public jsonDataService: 
           DataOrMethodCallService) {
                      this.el = el;
                       }
        ngOnInit() {
        this.jsonDataService.getdata().subscribe(
          res=> {
            this.loadData(res)
            }, err => {
           console.log(err);
            });

      }
        ngAfterViewInit() {
          this.activeTab('tab-1');            // set active tabcontent as 'tab-1';
              }
           loadEvtabsUL = ($event) => {
            this.tabsUL($event.param1);
                  }
        loadData(res){
    this.tabsData = res['tabsdata'];
    }            
              tabsUL(event): void {
               let tab_id = event.target.hash.replace('#', '');
               this.activeTab(tab_id);
                event.preventDefault();
                          }

                activeTab(id) {
                 let tabsEl = this.tabs.nativeElement;
                  this.removeActive(tabsEl.querySelectorAll('.active'));
                   this.setActive([
                   tabsEl.querySelector(`#${id}`),
                    tabsEl.querySelector(`[href="#${id}"]`).parentNode   //here error
                            ]);

                          }

            setActive(elems) {
                elems.forEach((el) => {
                     el.className += ' active';
                      });
                       }

                 removeActive(elems) {
                   elems.forEach((el) => {
                   el.className = el.className.replace(' active', '');
                     });
                     }
```

Comment: Your code is not indented properly, making it unreadable. But anyway, you're doing it wrong. Don't do DOM manipulation from your component. Add or remove css classes from your template, using `[class.active]="someCondition"`.

Comment: Can you help, by your way, that first tab and its first tab content should be active ie id="tab-1 active initially and then on corresponding 'tab' click show it content.    The link should not change at url.

Comment: @Nizet,  I am doing DOM Manipulation because I want internal navigation for tabs. I dont want to change my 'url' when I click on the tabs. If you have suitable answer please help.

Comment: See https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabset/tabset.ts for example, with demos here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/examples. it does the job just fine without any dom manipulation.